# How can I deactivate a link in Asp.net webforms if the target would return a 404?

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, webforms, http-status-code-404

In my web application, files are copied to a CDN asynchronously and may not be available when the user sees the page that links to them. The links are stored in the database before the file copy operation is completed. Therefore there may be a small window of time when the link displays but the backing file is not available. During this time, I would like to change the appearance of the link to reflect this.

How can I check for the existence of a document on the server before I display the link?

Comment: `How can I check for the existence of a document on the server` Do you mean that the check must be performed by your server, or do you meant that the check can be performed (user) client side to see if the file is on the CDN server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make a call from the server to the resource (make sure you set the timeout very short and consider using async/await) and check the status code. Then update the HyperLink control as appropriate.

Note it may not be worth it to do this, because the amount of time it takes to check might exceed the amount of time it takes for the file to "go live".

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(MyHyperLink.NavigateUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Timeout = 2000; //2 seconds
    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    {
        MyHyperLink.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Of course, you'll want to wrap in try/catch block to handle timeouts. Also, note that a DNS lookup can take 15 seconds [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: went with this one, since the requirement is specifically asp.net, not JQuery. Modified slightly to check for any non-200 result. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Something you could do on client side is:

```
$('a').each(function(){
   // do an ajax call to the href of 'this' and evaluate the result.
   // If it is 404, then disable the link
})
```

The same could be done without jQuery, in case you are not using this library.

If you have several links on your page it won't be very performance wise but that's something you'll have to analyze carefully.

Comment: +1 I like this solution better than my own. The question did state the check should be performed on the server though. Not sure how important that is.

Comment: @mason: He says "How can I check for the existence of a document on the server". Not sure if he's saying that the logic must be on the server or saying that the document is on the server. You can be 100% right though.

Comment: I did not even think of interpreting it like that!